# Less is more, and more is less

Tags: riddle

Less is more and more is less,
But let's go down the wondrous list -
Ignoring the one, so high and near,
And yet the lowest of all, I fear.

The dog's on top, then find your way,
The nearest, and a giant far away.
These are all above what's naught,
And yet in truth they are below.

So many more, some more, some less:
Shining beacons of hope, God bless.
Now you've read this tale bizarre,
Don't you wonder what they are?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this riddle describes

> Stars

Less is more and more is less, But let's go down the wondrous list -

> Less meaning less star magnitude - the lower it is, the brighter they appear.

Ignoring the one, so high and near, And yet the lowest of all, I fear.

> The Sun, our nearest star, is the lowest  magnitude at -27 and we will ignore it below, especially as the Sun isn't visible in the night sky.

The dog's on top, then find your way, The nearest, and a giant far away.

> *The dog's on top:* The brightest star in the Earth's night sky is the dog star aka [Sirius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirius) with a magnitude of -1.5 
>    *Find your way:* The next brightest star visible from Earth is Canopus,  with a magnitude of -0.7
>  Canopus was a navigator in Greek mythology.
>
>  *The nearest:* Then the next brightest is Alpha Centauri (star system) which is the nearest star after the Sun with a magnitude of -0.3 
>  *A giant far away:* Then Arcturus a red giant is −0.05

These are all above what's naught, And yet in truth they are below.

> Star [magnitudes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_(astronomy)) -  These are the only stars which have magnitudes below zero.  The next in the magnitude list is Vega which is positive at +0.4

So many more, some more, some less: Shining beacons of hope, God bless.
Now you've read this tale bizarre, Don't you wonder what they are?

> Twinkle, twinkle, little star, How I wonder what you are!
>
>   "Shining beacons of hope" -  Babylon 5

Comment: Good job! There are a few bits you haven't got though, especially in the second stanza.

Comment: Thanks for this puzzle! I've updated and hope I haven't made too many astronomical errors.

Comment: All correct. FTR, "find your way" was meant to refer to Canopus, a navigator in Greek mythology, and "Shining beacons of hope" is a very obscure Babylon 5 reference.